# DeltaTable update partitioning column values and drop old blob partitions?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, partitioning

I am updating a Delta Table using the merge command in Python described [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge). The table has been partitioned by the column "Number" beforehand, however these are the values I am actually updating. So the merge is supposed to sort the data into new partitions. However, if I run the Merge it creates new partitions based on the new "Number" values, while also keeping the old partitions in the Blob Storage (see blue circle). Is there a way to drop or overwrite the old partitions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I didn't realize that the old partitions are kept due to the versioning system. Old partitions can be removed using the DeltaTable vacuum function.